# Vue.js in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use vue.js with laravel for the first time.

In the blade.php file:

```
<html>
    <body class>
        <div id="app"> 
            <favourup></favourup>
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the app.js file:

```
Vue.component('favourup', require('./components/Favourup.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

In the vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>FavourUp</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am not getting any errors however the local host displays an empty web page when it should display 'FavourUp'

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` to compile the javascript? You can also run `npm run watch` to compile it on the fly when you work on your code

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Yes I have already run the dev command

Comment: Try with `mix` helper instead of `asset`: `<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`.

Comment: @Daniel the web page is still empty

Comment: we dont use `require()` on the client side, thats used on node.js. Also we usually register components with `components: { favourup: favourup }`

Comment: @Ifaruki How do I then import the favourUp.vue file into the app.js file?

Comment: usually with `import .. from ..` but this wont work on older browser. usually people go with webpack witch bundles them all together.

Answer (score 0):

you should write .default at end of require vue components because of part of the vue-loader 15 updates, if your code uses the CommonJS syntax for importing EcmaScript modules, you'll need to append .default:
https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade#importing-es-modules
but as @Ifaruki said you can import it too here's the code:

```
// first
Vue.component('favourup', require('./components/Favourup.vue').default);

// second
import Favourup from './components/Favourup.vue';

Vue.component('favourup', Favourup);
```